# typst horizontal display of 2 images?

Tags: math, markup, typesetting, typst

I am using typst to render some stuff, I want a side by side display of 2 images I gured out how to get things vertically:

```
#figure(
  (image("eulerian.svg", width: 10%),
  image("lagrangian.svg", width: 10%)).join(),
  caption: [A curious figure.],
) <glacier>
```

[image]

I am wondering how to get things horizontally now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@honkbug gives a good example but without an explanation of the solution. Thus, I want to show the document and what happens with different parameters.

### 1. Using `grid`

Typst has a function `grid`, which allows us to arrange contents. And this is the function we can use to place subfigures.

The most important parameter of `grid` is `columns` here:

> columns
>
> Either specify a track size array or provide an integer to create a grid with that many auto-sized columns.
>
> [See doc for more details.](https://typst.app/docs/reference/layout/grid/)

When we give only one integer number, `grid` will create auto-sized columns and place contents automatically. Say we have two images and want to put them side by side; we can achieve this in this simple way:

```
// A function to represent a virtual image
#let vimg(body) = {
    rect(width: 10mm, height: 5mm)[
        #text(body)
    ]
}

#figure(
    grid(
        columns: 2,     // 2 means 2 auto-sized columns
        gutter: 2mm,    // space between columns
        vimg("1"),
        vimg("2"),
    ),
    caption: "some caption"
)
```

And we get this as a result:
[image: 2 images side by side]

We tell Typst we need two auto-sized columns with 2mm between them. But what if we provide more than two images? Let's test with 3:

```
#figure(
    grid(
        columns: 2,
        gutter: 2mm,
        vimg("1"),
        vimg("2"),
        vimg("3"),
    ),
    caption: "some caption"
)
```

[image: 3 images in two columns]
Since we are still using two columns, Typst put the third one on the second row. And if we change the `columns` to `3`, they will be in the same row.

### 2. Using `stack`

We can also use `stack` to achieve the goal:

```
#figure(
    stack(
        dir: ltr,       // left-to-right
        spacing: 2mm,   // space between contents
        vimg("1"),
        vimg("2"),
    ),
    caption: "some caption"
)
```

Here we place the images in a horizontal stack with the direction `left-to-right.

[image: two images side by side with stack]

In this way, there is no `columns` to limit the number of pictures but we can only have one row. Thus, if we place too many images, they might be outside of the page.

Answer (score 3):

```
#figure(
    grid(
        columns: (auto, auto),
        rows:    (auto, auto),
        gutter: 1em,
        [ #image("eulerian.svg",   width: 80%) ],
        [ #image("lagrangian.svg", width: 80%) ],
    ),
    caption: [A curious figure.]
) <glacier>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add an explanation to the solution so future readers will understand it.